# Set highcharts y-axis min value to 0, unless there is negative data

Tags: highcharts, axis, default-value, minimum

I'm having an issue with highcharts where I have a number of different charts being generated by JSON calls.

For the majority of these charts I need the minimum y-axis value to be set at 0, however there are a couple of occasions where negative values need to be shown. How can I tell highcharts to have a minimum y-axis value of 0 only if there are no negative values in the data, is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Link to best/correct solution, if you are using Highcharts 5.0 and above https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105873/2952405

Answer (score 11):

The option that you're looking for is called `softMin` and was introduced in version **5.0.1**. The docs describe it as follows:

> A soft minimum for the axis. If the series data minimum is greater
>   than this, the axis will stay at this minimum, but if the series data
>   minimum is lower, the axis will flex to show all data.

```
yAxis: {
    softMin: 0
}
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.softMin

Answer (score 8):

You can add to your y-axis :

```
 yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Title of the y-axis'
            },
            min: 0 // this sets minimum values of y to 0
        },
```

Comment: this will always set the min to 0. 
the question asked "How can I tell highcharts to have a minimum y-axis value of 0 only if there are no negative values in the data"

Comment: Perfect solution. Save some UI space

Answer (score 7):

I achieved this by creating a function using [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)

```js
var setMin = function () {
  var chart = this,
  ex = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();

  // Sets the min value for the chart 
  var minVal = 0;

  if (ex.dataMin < 0) {
    minVal = ex.dataMin;
  }

  //set the min and return the values
  chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(minVal, null, true, false);
}
```

then in your chart, you call it like this:

```
$('#container').highcharts({ 
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: setMin
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set the "floor", this defines the minimum possible value for min. When negative values are added, they will not be visible! (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.floor)

```
yAxis: {
    floor: 0
}
```

I know this question has been asked a long time ago and this property did not exist at the time. But I just encounter this problem and I think others will be happy to not having to search.

Comment: in latest version this one works.
min:0 will also work

Answer (score 2):

You can prepare your own function which check is negative is or not, then set appropriate ticks. To achive this, you should use tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner